# MVC application Cookie AND Token authentication in Web Api project

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, oauth-2.0, jwt

I'm currently working on a project which has 2 clients. An `MVC` client and an `Android` client.

I've implemented `ASP .Net Identity` for the `authentication` of my `MVC` controllers. The `MVC` project also includes some web `API` controllers. In my views, I call both the controllers, as well as some ajax calls to my web `API`.

Question: Is it possible to, when I make an ajax call from browser to the web API (or controllers), to use `cookie based authentication`, but when I make an ajax call from the android app, use `token authentication`?

I'm using .Net Framework 4.6.1

Answer (score 0):

define two policies: one for the API (*apipolicy*) and the other for normal MVC calls (*defaultpolicy*) in Startup.cs in *ConfigureServices* metod this:

```
services.AddAuthorization(options =>
{
    // define several authorization policies if needed
    options.AddPolicy("defaultpolicy", b =>
    {
        b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
    });
    options.AddPolicy("apipolicy", b =>
    {
        b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        // define which authentication is used for this policy
        b.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
    });
});
```

to apply each policy you need to decorate controllers with the desired `[Authorize ("policy")]` Attribute like:

**SampleDataApiController.cs** - with apipolicy applied

```
[Authorize ("apipolicy")]
[Route("api/[controller]")]
public class SampleDataApiController : Controller
{
}
```

**AccountController.cs** - with defaultpolicy applied

```
[Authorize("defaultpolicy")]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
public class AccountController : Controller
{
}
```

As a sample here is my complete *ConfigureServices* method to give you an idea:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddMvc();

    services.AddAuthorization(options =>
    {
        options.AddPolicy("defaultpolicy", b =>
        {
            b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
        });
        options.AddPolicy("apipolicy", b =>
        {
            b.RequireAuthenticatedUser();
            b.AuthenticationSchemes.Add(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme);
        });
    });

    services.AddAuthentication(options =>
    {
        options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        options.DefaultChallengeScheme = "CustomScheme";
    })
    .AddCookie()
    .AddJwtBearer(options =>
    {
        // Bearer Logic
    })
    .AddOAuth("CustomScheme", options =>
    {
        // Oauth Logic
    });
}
```

I just added the following nuget for simplicity. *Microsoft.AspNetCore.All*

[image]

Comment: It seems that the  services.AddAuthorization and  services.AddAuthentication aren't recognized. Am I doing something wrong? I placed the ConfigureServices method in my startup.cs?

Comment: I'm using a dotnet core project. I added Microsoft.AspNetCore.All nuget package.

Comment: Aha! I'm using .NET Framework 4.6.1, not  the core version, I should have mentioned that. Can I still use your example in some way? I found a lot of .NET core examples but not for the normal framework.

Comment: unfortunately they are dotnet core specific. sorry.